# Uploading using FTP but website not adapting to changes (not cache)

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, ftp

I am developing a Wordpress theme for a blog I want to start.

I am using Dreamweaver to upload my files to the server using FTP. It appears that the FTP is working perfectly. I have edited files, uploaded, then checked on the server and the changes are being made.

The problem is the changed are not showing up on my website. They are showing up maybe 5 - 10 minutes after, if at all. The strange thing is .css files work and update perfectly, but the .php files do not.

The issue does not appear to be the cache. I am clearing cache, doing hard-refreshes and using incognito to develop.

Comment: this is because the servers in the middle may cache your static contents

Answer (score 0):

change your css links to

```
<link href="stack.css?ver=<?php echo rand(1,10000) ?>">
```

this may help

Answer (score 0):

You can press ctrl+r for refresh your page and check it . if still out put not come check then follow my suggestion.
1.check your file permission
2.wordpress disabled cache.
3.check htacces